# How to combine data at the same cell over a range of specific sheets using an indirect reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple sheets (S1, S2, S3...) which are all filled with identically formatted data (data tables).
For each row in my main sheet, I identify what cell in these lookup tables represents that entry and store that reference using ADDRESS(MATCH(), MATCH()).

I wish to use that reference to then use HSTACK() and import all of the relevant values from the data tables as a horizontal array.

This works when I enter the cell address manually:

```
=HSTACK(S1:S2!$O$18)
```

But when I try to use an indirect reference excel crashes immediately after entering the formula, without any kind of error message:

```
=HSTACK(S1:S2! INDIRECT(H2)), where H2 is the cell storing $O$18.
```

This gives an invalid cell reference error:

```
=HSTACK(INDIRECT("A:B!"&H2))
```

I am open to alternative formulas, but ideally, I would like to store the cell reference in advance to reduce the number of lookups I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDIRECT` doesn't work with 3D sheet references.

One option would be to list the relevant sheets within a *vertical* worksheet range  somewhere, for example `A1:A2`, after which you could use:

`=CELL("contents",INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(A1:A2)&"'!"&H2))`